# Double request on "next url"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, ruby-on-rails-3.2

- rails 3.2.13
- ruby 1.9.3

Hi, I'm adding next and prev urls for the best SEO results.
But I realized that I have 2 page requests (current page and next page) in my server log.

Here is a piece of my controller:

```
@recipes = Recipe.includes(:chef, :category).order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(9)

if @recipes.present? == true
   if @recipes.first_page? && @recipes.num_pages > 1
      ...
      @next_url = url_for(:page => (@recipes.current_page + 1))
      ...
   end
   ...
end
```

**But when the @next_url is called the entire page is requested. I just wanna to sum 1 to current url string.**

How could I resolve this?

**UPDATE:**

**The problem is the Firefox (21.0) on MAC. In other browser this request does not happen. It's a browser bad running! I can't fix it, unfortunately!**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I need to point out that

```
if @recipes.present? == true
```

is not a good coding practice, since @recipes.present? will actually return true or false

what you want to achieve with this piece of code?

```
  if @recipes.first_page? && @recipes.num_pages > 1
      ...
      @next_url = url_for(:page => (@recipes.current_page + 1))
      ...
   end
```

so if it is first page and the page number is greater than 1 then there will have @next_url?

should be OR || ,is it? can you explain what you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Nich, thanks for your answer! Sorry about my english and (fail) logic! I'm new on ruby/rails. Its a pagination page and I wanna to put, inside head, the link rel="next" and rel="prev" when is necessary.

In this case, should be AND because if I don't have other pages, the @nex_url don't be appear. I used the "num_pages > 1" to check if the page has a pagination.

Am I clear?

Comment: "num_pages" is the number of pages. So, if "num_pages" is greater than 1 we have the pagination, otherwise we have only one page (and don't have to appear the next_url).

Comment: hmm, for the pagination, try path instead and :page as a param.

Comment: I already tried this. The url generated is `receitas?page=2` but I wanna `receitas/pagina-2`. In this exemple I'm using "recipes_url" instead "url_for". `@next_url = recipes_url(:page => (@recipes.current_page + 1))`


My route is: `resources :recipes, :path => 'receitas', :id => /[0-9]+/ do
  match 'pagina-:page', :action => :index, :on => :collection # Kaminari
 end`
What am I missing here?

Comment: erm, I don't think it can achieve in yours way,it is better to stick with params. The url can't detect/GET the params

Comment: @Nick, I found the problem. Is the Firefox (21.0) on MAC. In other browser this request does not happen. It's a browser problem, I can't fix it!